# select from two sql views not using one of them

Tags: sql

I have this sql view, this is not my code:

```
SELECT
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`date` AS `date`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`book_title` AS `book_title`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`marketplace` AS `marketplace`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_avg_list_price` AS `amazon_kdp_avg_list_price`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_royalty_type` AS `amazon_kdp_royalty_type`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd` AS `amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_royalty_in_usd` AS `amazon_kdp_royalty_in_usd`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_paid_downloads` AS `amazon_kdp_paid_downloads`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_free_downloads` AS `amazon_kdp_free_downloads`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_ku_pages_read` AS `amazon_ku_pages_read`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_ku_revenue_in_usd` AS `amazon_ku_revenue_in_usd`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`create_space_revenue_in_usd` AS `create_space_revenue_in_usd`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`create_space_royalty_in_usd` AS `create_space_royalty_in_usd`,
    `view_combined_rev_data`.`create_space_paperbacks_sold` AS `create_space_paperbacks_sold`,
    (
        (
            `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_revenue_in_usd` + `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_ku_revenue_in_usd`
        ) + `view_combined_rev_data`.`create_space_revenue_in_usd`
    ) AS `daily_total_revenue`,
    (
        (
            `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_kdp_royalty_in_usd` + `view_combined_rev_data`.`create_space_royalty_in_usd`
        ) + `view_combined_rev_data`.`amazon_ku_revenue_in_usd`
    ) AS `daily_total_royalty`
FROM
    `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` `view_combined_rev_data`
```

My question is simple:
Why `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` is used in this line. I can't find the code using it anywhere else, so can I simply remove it?

```
FROM
    `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` `view_combined_rev_data`
```

Comment: That's the actual table name. view_combined_rev_data is a table alias. (A pretty long one...)

Answer (score 1):

This is your `FROM` clause:

```
FROM `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` `view_combined_rev_data`
```

The first name, `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` is the name of a table or view (presumably a view) that exists in the database.

The second name, `view_combined_rev_data`, is a *table alias*.  This is how the table/view is referred to in the query.

I recommend that you use table/view aliases that are abbreviations for the table/view name, something like this:

```
FROM `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` vcrmd
```

Then the references to columns would look like:

```
SELECT vcrmd.`date` AS `date`,
       vcrmd.`book_title` AS `book_title`,
       . . .
```

And this would further simplify to:

```
SELECT vcrmd.`date`,
       vcrmd.`book_title`,
       . . .
```

The *column alias* (name given after the `as`) is unnecessary in this case, because it defaults to the column name.  Note, though, that local coding styles may recommend having explicit column aliases.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM
    `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` `view_combined_rev_data`
```

These are not two views, but one view `view_combined_rev_marketplace_data` with an alias `view_combined_rev_data`.

When an alias is used to reference a table/view/function, then it must be used in the statement instead of the object's name. Usually aliases are meant to provide a shorter or more readable reference to the SQL object. In this case it is relatively long.